# Twilio video chat returns blob:null in src

Tags: javascript, html, twilio

I use Twilio API to create video chat. It works good for iPad, I got video and audio from laptop to my iPad, but I didn't see nothing from iPad to my web page (at the laptop):

```
<audio src="blob:null/cb84b2a9-be83-4db1-8313-61667b843865" autoplay></audio>
<video src="blob:null/492636ca-ce2f-4758-a866-2bf8ce9a08af" autoplay></video>
```

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/v1/twilio-video.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var accessToken = "..."
        const Video = Twilio.Video;
        const client = new Video.Client(accessToken);
        const localMedia = new Video.LocalMedia();

        Video.getUserMedia().then(mediaStream => {
            localMedia.addStream(mediaStream);
        });

        client.connect({
            to: 'my-room',
            localMedia: localMedia
        }).then(room => {
            const localParticipant = room.localParticipant;                       
            room.participants.forEach(participant => {                    
                participant.on('trackAdded', track => {
                    if (track.kind === 'audio') {
                        console.log('Added an AudioTrack %s', track.id);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Added a VideoTrack %s', track.id);
                    }
                });
                participant.on('trackRemoved', track => {
                    if (track.kind === 'audio') {
                        console.log('Removed an AudioTrack %s', track.id);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Removed a VideoTrack %s', track.id);
                    }
                });    
                participant.on('trackEnabled', track => {
                    if (track.kind === 'audio') {
                        console.log('Enabled AudioTrack %s', track.id);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Enabled VideoTrack %s', track.id);
                    }
                });    
                participant.on('trackDisabled', track => {
                    if (track.kind === 'audio') {
                        console.log('Disabled AudioTrack %s', track.id);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Disabled VideoTrack %s', track.id);
                    }
                });

                const element = participant.media.attach();
                document.body.appendChild(element);

                participant.media.tracks.forEach(track => {
                    track.attach('#track-view');
                });
            });

            room.once('participantConnected', participant => {
                console.log('Participant "%s" has connected to the Room', participant.identity);
            });

            room.once('participantDisconnected', participant => {                
                console.log('Participant "%s" has disconnected from Room', participant.identity);
            });

        }, error => {
            console.error('Failed to connect to the Room', error);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I also have error in console: **"Not allowed to load local resource: blob:null/492636ca-ce2f-4758-a866-2bf8ce9a08af"**

Comment: Are you trying at chrome or chromium browser? Where are `src` for `<video>` and `<audio>` element set?

Comment: Yes, I use Google Chrome ver. 56.0 on my Mac. Twilio js added <div> with <audio> and <video>, but src="blob:null.."

Comment: Launch chrome with `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag set.

Comment: can i get the access Tocken to run this example of fiddler ?

Comment: I executed in Terminal: "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" --allow-file-access-from-files, but I got the same error in console

Comment: Close open chrome instances or set `--user-data-dir` to a different directory than opened instance `$ chrome --allow-file-access-from-files --user-data-dir="~/.config/google-chrome-temp"`

Comment: Thanks for the help! It works now

Comment: @Kirill See also [How do I make the Google Chrome flag "--allow-file-access-from-files" permanent?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/160245/how-do-i-make-the-google-chrome-flag-allow-file-access-from-files-permanent/)